# Rabbitmq write throughput reduces as the number of queues increases

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using Rabbitmq 3.7.3 with Java client 5.1.2 [amqp-client-5.1.2.jar] . Having single queue I am able to write 25000 items per second. If I add one more queue and start writing on both the queues, then I am able write only 25000 items per second in both the queues. I.e., only around 12.5k per second per queue. Ideally I should be able to write 25k per second in every queue. Please help how should I configure the queues to achieve linear throughput across the queues. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you check your system behavior, specifically see if you're not reaching your filesystem limit? If you are, you should see a fair bit of IO wait during your tests, relating to the disk hosting the rabbitmq filesystem.

Comment: I suggest using the RabbitMQ [PerfTest](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html) tool to diagnose this. It is what the team uses to do performance tests.